# hard-coding "identity-pool id' for 'aws cognito' is dangerous in security?

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, unity-game-engine, amazon-iam, amazon-cognito

I am using aws cognito service for authentication with Unity3D.
I wonder whether there is security problem if 'identity-pool id' is hardcoded to script.
For the security, how do deveopers implement? 
Is there anybody to suggest?

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on releasing the source code, exposing identities and authentication information is a bad idea.

What you could do is make your code to fetch the Identity Pool ID from a separate file and commit that file that has the connection string, or in this case, your Identity Pool ID - but commit it with a template ID. Not the real one. After you've committed it you can use .gitignore to ignore that file and then change it to the real ID.

This way no one will see your ID, it's easy to manage and easy for others that are Forking/cloning your project understand what they need to do.

This is also a good practice if you, for instance, work together and everyone is for instance using a personal license or similar.

Comment: I understand that I should make a fake Identity Pool ID from certain file then..can not understand next step...Can you explain more about using .gitignore and changing it to the real ID? Thanks.

Comment: To take this answer just a bit further, be careful about scoping down the IAM roles that are created with your identity pool. These define what authenticated/unauthenticated users can do, so it'd help limit the blast radius if someone did gain improper access.

Comment: Jeff Bailey hi, I found aws link and discovered identity pool id can be hardcoded as cognito credential is embeded...Am I right? https://aws.amazon.com/ko/blogs/mobile/how-amazon-cognito-keeps-mobile-app-users-data-safe/

Comment: Answer above is, if your code is going to be pushed to github, pushing keys may allow bad actors to use your amazon account. Issues are different in protecting a distributed app/script from bad actors. Can a bad actor extract the ID and perform a DOS attack or expensive processes on my pool? I understand that in general the credentials are only provided to users authenticated through an authentication provider, but what prevents the creation of an app that mimics my app and performs undesired actions. Is the safety net purely IAM Roles?  Can anyone produce a mimic app?