# How sensitive is my identity pool id?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

**Background**

I've been working on a front end javascript application that consumes AWS resources (mostly Lambdas behind API Gateway).  The API Gateway resources are protected with IAM, and the app uses most of what Cognito offers accordingly.

This includes an Identity Pool with *Unauthenticated Identities* enabled, and federation with both a Cognito User Pool and multiple social and custom OIDC providers. Cognito is interacted with solely from our front end javascript code, using Amazon's SDK.

**Unauthenticated Identities**

The sensitivity of the ID pool id applies to all my use cases, but I'm most curious about the Unauthenticated use case.  We've been following what seems to be [Amazon's suggested approach](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp.html): Use Cognito or STS to get IAM keys, and use those keys to access AWS resources.  [I've even been spreading this gospel.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47125993/authentication-without-user-credentials/47126720#47126720)

This is all well and good, but it does require me to expose my identity pool id to the front end.  And the identity pool id is the only thing you need to get IAM keys for your Unauthenticated IAM role.

Theoretically, any attacker could grab my identity pool id and start abusing my resources (that are allowed for the Unauth IAM role) using the same Amazon SDKs that I use.

**The Question(s)**

- In a general sense, how sensitive should I consider an identity pool id to be?  Is it just A-ok to show this to anybody?
- If I decide it *is* sensitive enough to not expose to the browser, how do I deal with that?  Where and how do I hide it and get to it?
- In any case, should I "bake in" a way to rotate the id frequently?
- Are there (types of) use cases where it's ok to expose the id, and cases where it isn't?

**The answer(s) I'm looking for**

As noted in the linked answer above, my understanding is that the Unauthenticated Identities thing isn't bulletproof, and only provides a *reasonable* level of confidence that it's your app on the other end of the line.  In other words, while not impossible, it is at least *reasonably difficult* for someone to abuse your AWS back end using this model.

In addition to the bullet points above, I'd appreciate any critique of this understanding.  Am I underselling the security around unauthenticated IAM access to AWS?  Overselling it?

**Disclaimers**

I'll admit this question smells a lot like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40777433/hard-coding-identity-pool-id-for-aws-cognito-is-dangerous-in-security). I'm **not** asking about hard coding the identity pool id in my application; this is already fetched from a web service.  However, it's still completely exposed to the front end, and you can argue that it's actually *easier* to pull it out of an AJAX response than out of minified code.

I do lock the Unauth role down as tight as I can, and I understand that allowing anonymous access to stuff can only be so secure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it safe to show the AWS cognito pool ID in my html?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39837246/1695906)

Comment: The pool ID is *designed* to be exposed to the client -- and the answer to the other question you referenced seems to be based on a misunderstanding of the purpose of this value.  Much of the point of Cognito is to expose that, rather than real credentials.  The risk lies in the associated policies, just as the risk would lie in what *any* anonymous API allows.  If knowing your pool ID doesn't allow me to do anything I shouldn't, then I benefit nothing from knowing it.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - I specifically asked for critique of my understanding of how all this works, so I appreciate your comment.  I'm curious about what I'm misunderstanding in my linked to answer.  I do understand that I'm exposing an identity pool id instead of AWS credentials, and this is safer; this seems pretty basic. What about my answer led you to the conclusion that I'm misunderstanding something?  What don't I get?

Comment: Also, knowing my pool ID *does* allow you to do something you shouldn't.  It allows you to essentially spoof my site and access any resources allowed by the Unauth role/policy.  I want even Unauth requests to be fulfilled for my site, and my site only.  Do I need to resort to something nasty like IP checking to pull this off?

Comment: My comment about misunderstanding was actually a mistake on my part.  I was reading some other Q&A on the topic and the one I was referring to was actually not one of the ones you linked to.  I apologize for the confusion.

Comment: Knowing your pool id allows me to do things I shouldn't, in exactly the same way any kind of unauthenticated access does.  It feels like you have valid concerns but you're focusing on the ID as the problem, when it's really only a problem because it happens to be there.  Any other solution brings the same exact problem under a different label.  Proxy the anonymous requests through EC2 and sign them on the back-side, and now the problem shifts to being the fact that you are revealing anonymously-usable URLs in your HTML at all... yet you would not ask "is it safe to expose URLs in my HTML?"

Comment: IAM policies, of course, allow some protections similar to what you might impose on an ordinary web server, such as referer checking. Obviously the referer header is not immune to spoofing, but it would prevent blatant theft of service by someone copy/pasting your links into another web site since the typical user would have no way of knowing that they'd need to start spoofing headers in order for that other site to work.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - Thank you for elaborating, this is quality input.  _Any other solution brings the same exact problem under a different label._ certainly resonates with me.